# How do I split a string into a list of words?

Tags: python, string, list, split, text-segmentation

How do I split a sentence and store each word in a list? e.g.

```py
"these are words"   ⟶   ["these", "are", "words"]
```

---

<sub>To split on other delimiters, see [Split a string by a delimiter in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475251).</sub>

<sub>To split into individual characters, see [How do I split a string into a list of characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978787).</sub>

Comment: As it is, you will be printing the full list of words for each word in the list.  I think you meant to use `print(word)` as your last line.

Answer (score 557, accepted):

Given a string `sentence`, this stores each word in a list called `words`:

```
words = sentence.split()
```

Comment: This does not eliminate the special symbols such as commas and points

Answer (score 483):

To split the string `text` on any consecutive runs of whitespace:

```
words = text.split()
```

To split the string `text` on a custom delimiter such as `","`:

```
words = text.split(",")
```

The `words` variable will be a `list` and contain the words from `text` split on the delimiter.

Answer (score 95):

Use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> Return a **list of the words** in the string, using *sep* as the delimiter
> ... If *sep* is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.

```
>>> line = "a sentence with a few words"
>>> line.split()
['a', 'sentence', 'with', 'a', 'few', 'words']
```

Answer (score 62):

Depending on what you plan to do with your sentence-as-a-list, you may want to look at the [Natural Language Took Kit](http://www.nltk.org/).  It deals heavily with text processing and evaluation. You can also use it to solve your problem:

```
import nltk
words = nltk.word_tokenize(raw_sentence)
```

This has the added benefit of splitting out punctuation.

Example:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> s = "The fox's foot grazed the sleeping dog, waking it."
>>> words = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
>>> words
['The', 'fox', "'s", 'foot', 'grazed', 'the', 'sleeping', 'dog', ',', 
'waking', 'it', '.']
```

This allows you to filter out any punctuation you don't want and use only words.

Please note that the other solutions using `string.split()` are better if you don't plan on doing any complex manipulation of the sentence.

[Edited]

Comment: `split()` relies on white-space as the separator, so it will fail to separate hyphenated words--and long-dash separated phrases will fail to split too. And if the sentence contains any punctuation without spaces, those will fail to stick. For any real-world text parsing (like for this comment), your nltk suggestion is much better than split()`.

Comment: Potentially useful, although I wouldn't characterise this as splitting into "words". By any plain English definition, `','` and `"'s"` are not words. Normally, if you wanted to split the sentence above into "words" in a punctuation-aware way, you'd want to strip out the comma and get `"fox's"` as a single word.

Comment: Python 2.7+ as of April 2016.

Answer (score 37):

How about this algorithm? Split text on whitespace, then trim punctuation. This carefully removes punctuation from the edge of words, without harming apostrophes inside words such as `we're`.

```
>>> text
"'Oh, you can't help that,' said the Cat: 'we're all mad here. I'm mad. You're mad.'"

>>> text.split()
["'Oh,", 'you', "can't", 'help', "that,'", 'said', 'the', 'Cat:', "'we're", 'all', 'mad', 'here.', "I'm", 'mad.', "You're", "mad.'"]

>>> import string
>>> [word.strip(string.punctuation) for word in text.split()]
['Oh', 'you', "can't", 'help', 'that', 'said', 'the', 'Cat', "we're", 'all', 'mad', 'here', "I'm", 'mad', "You're", 'mad']
```

Comment: Nice, but some English words truly contain trailing punctuation. For example, the trailing dots in `e.g.` and `Mrs.`, and the trailing apostrophe in the possessive `frogs'` (as in `frogs' legs`) are part of the word, but will be stripped by this algorithm. Handling abbreviations correctly can be *roughly* achieved by detecting dot-separated initialisms plus using a dictionary of special cases (like `Mr.`, `Mrs.`). Distinguishing possessive apostrophes from single quotes is dramatically harder, since it requires parsing the grammar of the sentence in which the word is contained.

Comment: @MarkAmery You're right. It's also since occurred to me that some punctuation marks—such as the em dash—can separate words without spaces.

Answer (score 17):

> I want my python function to split a sentence (input) and store each word in a list

The `str().split()` method does this, it takes a string, splits it into a list:

```
>>> the_string = "this is a sentence"
>>> words = the_string.split(" ")
>>> print(words)
['this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence']
>>> type(words)
<type 'list'> # or <class 'list'> in Python 3.0
```

Answer (score 16):

[shlex](https://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html) has a [`.split()`](https://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) function. It differs from `str.split()` in that it does not preserve quotes and treats a quoted phrase as a single word:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split("sudo echo 'foo && bar'")
['sudo', 'echo', 'foo && bar']
```

NB: it works well for Unix-like command line strings. It doesn't work for natural-language processing.

Comment: Use with caution, especially for NLP. It will crash on single quote strings like `"It's good."` with `ValueError: No closing quotation`

Answer (score 16):

If you want all the chars of a **word/sentence** in a list, do this:

```
print(list("word"))
#  ['w', 'o', 'r', 'd']


print(list("some sentence"))
#  ['s', 'o', 'm', 'e', ' ', 's', 'e', 'n', 't', 'e', 'n', 'c', 'e']
```

Comment: This answer belongs on https://stackoverflow.com/q/4978787 instead, although it's probably a duplicate of existing answers there.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to split a string into a list of words and if the string has punctuations, it's probably advisable to remove them. For example, `str.split()` the following string as

```py
s = "Hi, these are words; these're, also, words."
words = s.split()
# ['Hi,', 'these', 'are', 'words;', "these're,", 'also,', 'words.']
```

where `Hi,`, `words;`, `also,` etc. have punctuation attached to them. Python has a built-in `string` module that has a string of punctuations as an attribute (`string.punctuation`). One way to get rid of the punctuations is to simply strip them from each word:

```py
import string
words = [w.strip(string.punctuation) for w in s.split()]
# ['Hi', 'these', 'are', 'words', "these're", 'also', 'words']
```

another is make a comprehensive dictionary of the strings to remove

```py
table = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
words = s.translate(table).split() 
# ['Hi', 'these', 'are', 'words', 'thesere', 'also', 'words']
```

It doesn't handle words like `these're`, so it handle that case `nltk.word_tokenize` could be used as [tgray suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/744046/19123103). Only, filter out the words that consist entirely of punctuation.

```py
import nltk
words = [w for w in nltk.word_tokenize(s) if w not in string.punctuation]
# ['Hi', 'these', 'are', 'words', 'these', "'re", 'also', 'words']
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the words without without harming apostrophes inside words
Please find the input_1 and input_2 Moore's law

```
def split_into_words(line):
    import re
    word_regex_improved = r"(\w[\w']*\w|\w)"
    word_matcher = re.compile(word_regex_improved)
    return word_matcher.findall(line)

#Example 1

input_1 = "computational power (see Moore's law) and "
split_into_words(input_1)

# output 
['computational', 'power', 'see', "Moore's", 'law', 'and']

#Example 2

input_2 = """Oh, you can't help that,' said the Cat: 'we're all mad here. I'm mad. You're mad."""

split_into_words(input_2)
#output
['Oh',
 'you',
 "can't",
 'help',
 'that',
 'said',
 'the',
 'Cat',
 "we're",
 'all',
 'mad',
 'here',
 "I'm",
 'mad',
 "You're",
 'mad']
```