# Split a string by a delimiter in Python

Tags: python, string, list, split

How to split this string where `__` is the delimiter

```
MATCHES__STRING
```

To get an output of `['MATCHES', 'STRING']`?

---

<sub>For splitting specifically on whitespace, see [How do I split a string into a list of words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/).</sub>

<sub>To extract everything before the **first** delimiter, see [Splitting on first occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903557).</sub>

<sub>To extract everything before the **last** delimiter, see [partition string in python and get value of last segment after colon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169324).</sub>

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: It is worth to read the python standard documents and trying to understand few programs others have made to start to grasp basics of Python. Practise and copying/modifying are great tools to learn language.

Answer (score 401, accepted):

You can use the [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method: `string.split('__')`

```
>>> "MATCHES__STRING".split("__")
['MATCHES', 'STRING']
```

Comment: I was wondering, what is the difference between the first example (simply using split()) and the second example (with a for loop)?

Comment: @EndenDragon The for loop will automatically apply `x.strip()` and return a list of matches without whitespace on either side. The devil is in the details.

Comment: Hey, since this is a very popular question, I edited it to ask only 1 specific question and removed the part with the spaces around the delimiter because it wasn't clear what the OP even expected to happen (Since there never was a question in the question). I think the question (and answers) are more useful this way, but feel free to rollback all the edits if you disagree.

Comment: Often you just want one part of the `splitted` string. Get it with `'match'.split('delim')[0]` for the first one, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You may be interested in the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module, which is designed for comma-separated files but can be easily modified to use a custom delimiter.

```
import csv
csv.register_dialect( "myDialect", delimiter = "__", <other-options> )
lines = [ "MATCHES__STRING" ]

for row in csv.reader( lines ):
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Besides `split` and `rsplit`, there is `partition`/`rpartition`. It separates string *once*, but the way question was asked, it may apply as well.

Example:

```py
>>> "MATCHES__STRING".partition("__")
('MATCHES', '__', 'STRING')

>>> "MATCHES__STRING".partition("__")[::2]
('MATCHES', 'STRING')
```

And a bit faster then `split("_",1)`:

```
$ python -m timeit "'validate_field_name'.split('_', 1)[-1]"
2000000 loops, best of 5: 136 nsec per loop

$ python -m timeit "'validate_field_name'.partition('_')[-1]"
2000000 loops, best of 5: 108 nsec per loop
```

Timeit lines are based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47903325/3921746)

Answer (score 2):

When you have two or more elements in the string (in the example below there are three), then you can use a comma to separate these items:

```py
date, time, event_name = ev.get_text(separator='@').split("@")
```

After this line of code, the three variables will have values from three parts of the variable `ev`.

So, if the variable `ev` contains this string and we apply separator `@`:

```
Sa., 23. März@19:00@Klavier + Orchester: SPEZIAL
```

Then, after the `split` operation the variable

- `date` will have value `Sa., 23. März`
- `time` will have value `19:00`
- `event_name` will have value `Klavier + Orchester: SPEZIAL`

Comment: "*then you can use a comma*" It's called [unpacking a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34308337/2745495).

Answer (score 2):

For Python 3.8, you actually don't need the `get_text` method, you can just go with `ev.split("@")`, as a matter of fact the `get_text` method is throwing an att. error.
So if you have a string variable, for example:

```
filename = 'file/foo/bar/fox'
```

You can just split that into different variables with comas as suggested in the above comment but with a correction:

```
W, X, Y, Z = filename.split('_') 
W = 'file' 
X = 'foo'
Y = 'bar'
Z = 'fox'
```