# split with regex operators in python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a text file in that

```
line="File Creation Time:    2017-01-30T10:04:54.295767-08:00"
```

I have to split it with as a key and value pairs.
Below is my code:

```
 l = line.split(':', 1)
```

but I want to do it using regex operators.

Comment: This looks close to what you're looking for, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609922/how-can-i-split-a-string-at-the-first-occurrence-of-a-letter-in-python

Comment: but I read `split` or `partition` are the best solution for this

Comment: Any try on regexp part? Because this seems like `write teh regex` for me. Also, why do you _need_ regexp specifically? Does `split` not satisfy your needs?