# how to split the data to get the desired Output in python?

Tags: python, string, split

i have a input and i want to split the text to get the desired output i have used `txt.split(":")[-1]` but it's not solving my issue.Need help new to python coding.

input:`End Date: 10-09-2020 10:00 AM` 
Desired output: `10-09-2020 10:00 AM`

Comment: If you want to go with your approach, you probably need to use strip() and .join() to get to your desired output

Comment: did you `print (txt.split(":"))` - why do you use `[-1]` ? what can you change in your code to get what you want? did you read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)?

Comment: Duplicate:  [splitting-on-first-occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903557/splitting-on-first-occurrence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
txt.split("End Date:")[-1]
```

it will solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
input = "End Date: 10-09-2020 10:00 AM"
matcher = "End Date: " # get a constant identifier to look for

# now we want to slice the string in such way that leaves only the part 
# after the matcher. So we find the first occurence of matcher and then
# add it's length to see where is the end of the matcher. then we
# simply take the remaining string
desired = input[input.find(matcher)+len(matcher):]
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner  correct, and using input[10:] works as well