# Yet another regex string match

Tags: python, regex

I've been at it, for ~4 hours now, and I've failed completely, so I humbly ask for help

I've got a string with the following structure

```
a197 8101 aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd.doc
```

I need a regex that will give me `ddd.doc`. Obviously ddd is not always ddd, might be 'potato', might contain numerals etc. Basically I want regex that will give my anything between the last '/' and up until (including) .doc

Edit: `\/(.*\.html)` this is the closest I've got but it will return `/bbb/ccc/ddd.doc`

Edit2: I'm not looking to split, maybe I misspoke. I just want to match

Comment: Use `r'/([^/]+?\.doc)$'` in `re.findall`

Comment: https://frightanic.com/software-development/regex-match-last-occurrence/

Comment: Can you please show what 4 hours of trying has yielded so we can better teach?

Comment: @SterlingArcher I just edited my post to include that

Comment: Would the following link be [helpfull](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6169324/9758194)

Comment: @JvdV thanks but no, I'm not looking to split anything, and doing so on a '/' would be suicide as I have a LOT of them

Comment: @RahulKhanna thank you very much, for your wisdom, but I don't need to split anything :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `result = yourstring.rsplit('/',maxsplit=1)[1]` will actually be faster than any regexp-based solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"/([^/\\]+.doc)")
print(pattern.search("a197 8101 aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd.doc").group(1))
print(pattern.search("a197 8101 aaa/bbb/ccc/potato.doc").group(1))
print(pattern.search("a197 8101 aaa/bbb/ccc/01_-2,,.3.doc").group(1))
```

output:

```
ddd.doc
potato.doc
01_-2,,.3.doc
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
import re

string="a197 8101 aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd.doc"
result = re.findall(r'\w+\.\w+$', string)
print(result)
```

Comment: Depending on what is included in the "etc" in the question, \w may or may not suffice. 

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

string = "a197 8101 aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd.doc"
# parenthesis forms regex groups
# (group 1 matches start of line to and including /, greedily) = (^.*\/)
# (group 2 matches any character, non-greedy, until end of line) = (.*?$)
result = re.search(r'(^.*\/)(.*?$)', string)
print(result.group(0))
print(result.group(1))
print(result.group(2))

output = result.group(2)
```

will yield:

```
a197 8101 aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd.doc
a197 8101 aaa/bbb/ccc/
ddd.doc
```

Note that group 0 will always be the whole match.