# Unpack list to variables

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
row = ["Title", "url", 33, "title2", "keyword"]
```

Is there a more pythonic way to unpack this values like:

```
title, url, price, title2, keyword = row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]
```

Comment: `title, url, price, title2, keyword = row`?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Something like this?

```
>>> row = ["Title", "url", 33, "title2", "keyword"]
>>> title, url, price, title2, keyword = row
```

Answer (score 35):

Also if you need only few first variables, in Python 3 you can use:

```
row = ["Title", "url", 33, "title2", "keyword"]
title, url, *_ = row
```

It's a nice way to extract few first values without using explicit indices

Comment: could you please advice the pythonic way how to extract **last** value explicitly?

Comment: @Madness I don't know how to extract both few first values and few last values, but you can extract last values only by applying reverse to the list and then using the above-mentioned syntax

Comment: @Madness how about `*_, last = row` or `last = row[-1]`?

Answer (score 11):

In fact, python automatically unpacks containers when variables are separated by commas. This assigns each element in `row` to the variables on the left:

```
title, url, price, title2, keyword = row
```

After this assignment, `title` has the value of "Title", `price` has the value of 33, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You could also unpack it easily to a class or `namedtuple`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

row = ["Title", "url", 33, "title2", "keyword"]

Entry = namedtuple("Entry", "title url price title2 keyword")
new_entry  = Entry(*row)
print(new_entry.title) # Title
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way simple tuple/list packing
- Note ',' after *row

```
*row, = ["Title", "url", 33, "title2", "keyword"]  # creates a tuple of row elements
title, url, price, title2, keyword = row  # list unpacking unpacked here
for i in range(len(row)):
    print(row[i])
print()
print(title)
```

```
Title
url
33
title2
keyword

Title
```

Comment: That's not the intended use case for star assignments. There's no reason to include the `*` and `,` in this situation. A better example of their use is in Aleksandr's answer above.