# Python 3 extract html information from page

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I have been doing some googling but I can't really find a good python3 solution to my problem. Given the following HTML code, how do I extract 2019, 0.7 and 4.50% using python3?

```
<td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle'>2019</td><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>4.50%</td><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0.7</td>   <td>SGD0.2      </td>
```

Comment: Do you know there is ```BeautifulSoup```?, if not then check: 
 https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle'>2019</td><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>4.50%</td><td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;'>SGD 0.7</td>   <td>SGD0.2      </td>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

info_1, info_2, info_3, *_ = soup.select('td')

info_1 = info_1.get_text(strip=True)
info_2 = info_2.get_text(strip=True)
info_3 = info_3.get_text(strip=True).split()[-1]

print(info_1, info_2, info_3)
```

Prints:

```
2019 4.50% 0.7
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me what *_  is? I don't really understand how this code works

Comment: @user3702643 `a, b, *rest = [1, 2, 3, 4]` is standard python syntax for unpacking iterables (list, tuples, ...) to variables. After this `a` will be `1`, `b` will be `2` and `rest` will be `[3, 4]`. More here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34308337/unpack-list-to-variables

Comment: What happens if you have a few other <td> earlier to this required <td>? This is quite possible if this is a table. @user3702643 needs to take care of this when implementing.

Comment: @Prateek It depends from page to page, each page has it's structure different. OP has to modify the CSS selector(s) accordingly.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I think he might be right. It is a huge html document from which i only need to extract the above information

Comment: @user3702643 Does this html document have any unique selector ? I can help improve the answer.

Comment: @user3702643 The correct way is to open new question. Accept one of answer here to close this question, and open new question where you specify the URL of the document (or put short sample from it) and expected output.

Answer (score -1):

I think this might be helpful if does not exactly answer your question:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_data(self, data):
        print(data)

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed("<Your HTML here>")
```

For your particular case this will return:
2019
4.50%
SGD 0.7
SGD0.2

Comment: if it doesn't answer the question how it can be helpful?

Comment: it is because it provides something that is very close to the actual data that he needs. please read the question and then my answer :)

Comment: Please focus on quality answers :)