# A python program that's supposed to get 2 variables each iteration, separated by space, a str and an int, and end when the first one is '#'

Tags: python, loops, input, space

I tried the code below but it doesn't work because the input requires two values, so if I input '#', it shows a ValueError

```
  x = '0'
while(x != '#'):
   x, y = map(str, input().split())
   y = int(y)
   if x != '#':
       if y >= 90:
           print(f"{x} Alta")
       if y < 90:
           print(f"{x} Internação")
   else:
       break
```

Comment: Because it needs 2 character. there are 2 variables ```x,y```

Comment: So check for `'#'` before trying to split it.

Comment: Note.. if you tested for y >= 90 then you don't need to test for y < 90.. just use "else".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to put a prompt in the `input` call.

Writing 2 integer values work fine, for example `14 15`.
But if I put just one value, for example `14` then it crashes :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PycharmProjects/stack_overflow/68042991.py", line 3, in <module>
    x, y = map(str, input("type 2 integer values : ").split())
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

The same happens with the expected single value `#`.

That's because :

```py
>>> "14 15".split()  # what `split` gives us when applied to the user `input`
['14', '15']
>>> list(map(str, ['14', '15']))  # mapping to strings
['14', '15']
>>> x, y = ['14', '15']  # and tuple-unpacking it into the 2 variables
>>> x  # gives use the expected result
'14'
>>> y
'15'
>>> "14".split()  # but what if the user `input`ed only one value ?
['14']  # it gets splitted into a list of length 1
>>> x, y = ['14']  # which can't be tuple-unpacked
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Tuple unpacking is explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34308337/11384184)'s answers, I encourage you to read them.

Because of your assignment, Python expects to find two values in the iterable result of the `map` function, so when it finds only one, it fails.

The same happens if the user input is empty (or just whitespaces, due to `split`).
The same happens if the user input is more than 2 values (for example `14 15 16`).

Your code does not handle it properly.

The pythonic way to do it is :

```py
   the_user_input = input("type 2 integer values : ")
   try:
       x, y = the_user_input.split()
   except ValueError:  # unpacking error
       ...  # what to do in case of an error
   else:
       ...  # do what's next
```

I could not find a Pythonic way to add the handling of `#` in it.

But I personnaly prefer not to use `try/except` too much :

```py
   the_splitted_user_input = input("type 2 integer values : ").split()
   if len(the_splitted_user_input) == 1 and the_splitted_user_input[0] == "#":
       break
   if len(the_splitted_user_input) == 2:
       x, y = the_splitted_user_input  # assured to work
       ...  # do what's next
   else:
       ...  # what to do in case of an error
```

If you want to force the user to type correct values, you can wrap it up in a `while` loop, and/or extract it into a function.

Also, because you break out of you while loop if `x == '#'` then your while condition `x != '#'` is redundant.