# Reading from file and formatting into two dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, text, split, strip

I'm attempting to read data from multiple text files and move the data into a two-dimensional array. The data needs to remain in a specific order.

Could regex assist with this?

If you have any insight on how to improve this section of the code please let me know.

Comment: Why don't you grab the year from the 3rd line in the file?

Answer (score 2):

the [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/datetime.html) provides (most) everything date-related

```
from datetime import datetime

date = "Sat 30-Mar-1996 7:40 PM"
fmt = "%a %d-%b-%Y %I:%M %p"
a = datetime.strptime(date, fmt)
print(a.year)
>>> 1996
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the date-time string very easily by splitting its components and using [iterable unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34308337/unpack-list-to-variables), e.g.,

```
def parse_date(d):
    day_of_week, date, hhmm, ampm =  d.split()
    day_of_month, month, year = date.split('-')
    hour, minute = hhmm.split(':')
    return (year, month, day_of_month,
            ​hour if ampm=='AM' or str(int(hour)+12), minute,
            day_of_week)
```

and later, in the body of the loop

```
year, m, dom, ​h, m, dow  = parse_date(fields[-1].strip())
```

or, if you are interested only in `year`

```
year, *_ = parse_date(fields[-1].strip())
```

Answer (score -1):

You're probably looking for regular expressions, which are a very powerful way to analyze and extract data from strings. For an intro into them, I'd check out [this site](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) or [the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#regex-howto), but in your case I think you probably want something like '| ([a-zA-Z]*) ([0-9]*)-([a-zA-Z]*)-([0-9]*) ([0-9:]* [a-zA-Z]*) |' would work. A more specific description of the format the time would be in is necessary for a 100% correct regex [short for regular expressions].

To use regex in python, you want [the `re` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). First, create the pattern matcher with `matcher = re.compile(your_regex_string_here)`. Then, find the match with `result = matcher.match(file_contents)`. (You could also just do `result = re.match(regex_string,file_contents)`.) Whatever your regex, anything surrounded by parentheses is known as a "capturing group", which can be extracted from the result with `result.group()`; `result.group(0)` will return full match, and `result.group(n)` will return the contents of the nth capturing group - that is, the nth set of parentheses. In the above example, `result.group(4)` would return the year, though you could get any of the day of the week, day, month, year, and time by using groups 1-5.

The DateTime module as mentioned in another answer is also a great tool.

Comment: No, you don't need regex for this. You need to parse the date/time, which is already in a list.

Comment: And that's a terrible regex to use, it'll capture everything. Don't try to rewrite the `datetime` module. Use the right tool for the job, and regex is NOT the right tool for this job.

Comment: Just look at [this](https://regex101.com/r/gmMuvf/1) on regex101.com. Did you even think about testing your regex before posting it? And I was a little off - it doesn't match *every*thing, it only matches between every single character, so all the results will be `None`. Nice job.