# Iterate over string starting at a specific character

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a string that is a repeating decimal. The string value may or may not have values to the left of the decimal: ".33333333" or "1.6666666666" or "12125.464646464646".

I want to iterate through the string starting directly after the decimal. Is there a way to start a for loop directly to the right of the decimal?

Ideally, you would not cut or split the string in advance. The question is more geared towards starting a for loop at a specific point given a specific character versus looping through a full string that has been cut.

.333333 would start at 3

1.66666 would start at 6

12125.464646 would start at 4

Comment: Yep. Try: `for a in s[s.index('.')+1:]:`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a string by a delimiter in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475251/split-a-string-by-a-delimiter-in-python)

Comment: @AnomitraSaha I wasn't looking to split MYGz got what I was looking for

Comment: @MYGz @AnomitraSaha That's equivalent to `str.split` in that it creates a copy of the decimal digits.

Comment: @Mazzone `for a in s.split['.'][1]:` is the exact equivalent of what @MYGz wrote.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. One possible way is to use `find()`,

```
inp = "12125.464646464646"
for x in xrange(inp.find('.')+1, len(inp)):
  print inp[x],
```

Also you can try,

```
inp = "12125.464646464646"
for a in inp[inp.find('.')+1:]:
```

Comment: Maybe point the OP in the direction of the Python docs? Teach a man to fish and all that faff...

Comment: Teach a person the method name and they can google it themselves.

Comment: I didn't mean the docs of this method in particular. Just the Python docs overall (like a more polite way of saying RTFM).

Answer (score 0):

Try with `split`,

```
a="12125.464646464646"
for i in a.split('.')[-1]:
     print i
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this simplified code

```
 a="12125.464646464646"
 print [i for i in a.split('.')[1]]
 #output:- ['4', '6', '4', '6', '4', '6', '4', '6', '4', '6', '4', '6']
```