# how to reformat a text paragrath using python

Tags: python, string, text

Hi I was wondering how I could format a large text file by adding line breaks after certain characters or words. For instance, everytime a comma was in the paragraph could I use python to make this output an extra linebreak.

Comment: Sounds like a better job for sed (https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html). Something like `sed ‘s/,/,\n/’`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a string by a delimiter in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475251/split-a-string-by-a-delimiter-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can do using str.replace() in python. Check out the below code, replacing every `,` with `,\n`.

```
string = ""
with open('test.txt','r') as myfile:
  for line in myfile:
    string += line.replace(",",",\n")
myfile.close()
myfile = open('test.txt','w')
myfile.write(string)
```

File before execution:

```
Hello World and again HelloWorld,sdjakljsljsfs,asdgrwcfdssaasf,sdfoieunvsfaf,asdasdafjslkj,
```

After Execution:

```
Hello World and again HelloWorld,
sdjakljsljsfs,
asdgrwcfdssaasf,
sdfoieunvsfaf,
asdasdafjslkj,
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `''.replace()` method like so:

`'roses can be blue, red, white'.replace(',' , ',\n')` gives 
`'roses can be blue,\n red,\n white'` efectively inserting `'\n'` after every `,`