# How to convert string without quotation marks to the python array?

Tags: python, csv

Is it possible in Python to convert a raw string divided by commas, e.g.

```
tt0099700,tt0096061,tt0118688,tt0120784
```

into a Python array/list?

Such string is in loop as a variable `row[i]`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python import csv to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662571/python-import-csv-to-list)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a string by a delimiter in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475251/split-a-string-by-a-delimiter-in-python)

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
input_list = 'tt0099700,tt0096061,tt0118688,tt0120784'
new_list = input_list.split(',')
```

Output of `new_list`:

```
['tt0099700', 'tt0096061', 'tt0118688', 'tt0120784']
```