# Split in Hourly report using python

Tags: python

I need to get a split in hourly report .

Like today is 13th and its 5th hr,then my report should be like this:

```
13th 1st hr | 13th 2nd hr| 13th 3rd hr| 13th 4th hr |13th 5th hr|
```

I need to get like this split in the hours.

Not able to get any idea. Can someone help?

I finally cracked it i was not asking for split in the string i was asking for hours split.

i have done as below:

```
x = datetime.datetime.now()
print x

k= x.strftime("%H")
print k
```

k would be present hour

output ::
2019-05-16 17:59:52.806000

k=17

```
j = int(k)
for i in range(0,j):
     if(i <=9):
        num1='0'+str(i)
        len = "start_date= {}:00:00&end_date= {}:59:59".format(num1,num1)
     else:
       num1=i
       len = "start_date= {}:00:00&end_date= {}:59:59".format(num1,num1)
```

output::
start_date= 00:00:00&end_date= 00:59:59

start_date= 01:00:00&end_date= 01:59:59
.
.till 
.
start_date= 17:00:00&end_date= 17:59:59

This hour split i asked for not string split.

Comment: What is your input and what is your output?

Comment: It can probably be done with `re.split()` with regex or just a simple `str.split()` if you are confident in the input format. First, split the string by the `|` character, then for each of those subsets, split by spaces. The reason why I suggested using the `re` library is that you can also filter out non-numbers in the final step and account for leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: What is your input? Are there always spaces around pipes (`|`) or is it a varying factor in your output?

Comment: please share what you tried in code, any info about inputs and output, the question is not clear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a string by a delimiter in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475251/split-a-string-by-a-delimiter-in-python)

Comment: Your question is not clear.  First you ask for a split, but now it seem that you want to turn -- 1st hr -- into something using datetime.  Please be more specific in the terms of the output desired.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understand your intent. Assuming you meant this is a string such as:

```
"13th 1st hr | 13th 2nd hr| 13th 3rd hr| 13th 4th hr |13th 5th hr|"
```

You can `.split()` it like:

```
my_log = "13th 1st hr | 13th 2nd hr| 13th 3rd hr| 13th 4th hr |13th 5th hr|"
separate = my_log.split("|")
for log_item in separate:
    print(log_item)
```

Which prints:

```
13th 1st hr 
 13th 2nd hr
 13th 3rd hr
 13th 4th hr
```

If you additionally would like to strip the whitespace so it is level:

```
my_log = "13th 1st hr | 13th 2nd hr| 13th 3rd hr| 13th 4th hr |13th 5th hr|"
separate = my_log.split("|")
for log_item in separate:
    print(log_item.strip())
```

Prints more cleanly:

```
13th 1st hr
13th 2nd hr
13th 3rd hr
13th 4th hr
13th 5th hr
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are asking about splitting strings in python you can use `split()`

```
datastr = "13th 1st hr | 13th 2nd hr"
datalist = datastr.split("|")
for d in datalist:
    print(d)
```