# How to split words in line of a file separated by ";"

Tags: python, line

How to split the words in line separated by `;`:

```
10103;Baldwin, C;SFEN
10115;Wyatt, X;SFEN
10172;Forbes, I;SFEN
10175;Erickson, D;SFEN
10183;Chapman, O;SFEN
11399;Cordova, I;SYEN
11461;Wright, U;SYEN
11658;Kelly, P;SYEN
11714;Morton, A;SYEN
11788;Fuller, E;SYEN
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a string by a delimiter in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475251/split-a-string-by-a-delimiter-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```
line = "10103;Baldwin, C;SFEN 10115;Wyatt, X;SFEN 10172;Forbes, I;SFEN 10175;Erickson, D;SFEN 10183;Chapman, O;SFEN 11399;Cordova, I;SYEN 11461;Wright, U;SYEN 11658;Kelly, P;SYEN 11714;Morton, A;SYEN 11788;Fuller, E;SYEN"
line.split(";")
```

Output

```
['10103',
 'Baldwin, C',
 'SFEN 10115',
 'Wyatt, X',
 'SFEN 10172',
 'Forbes, I',
 'SFEN 10175',
 'Erickson, D',
 'SFEN 10183',
 'Chapman, O',
 'SFEN 11399',
 'Cordova, I',
 'SYEN 11461',
 'Wright, U',
 'SYEN 11658',
 'Kelly, P',
 'SYEN 11714',
 'Morton, A',
 'SYEN 11788',
 'Fuller, E',
 'SYEN']
```

Answer (score 0):

one alternative:

```
"10103;Baldwin, C;SFEN".split(";")
```

However, I think you want to separate everything (including the commas)so I would do a replace of the ";" first into commas and then doing the split by commas.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `csv` for this, although if your input is actually a string then you'll need `io.StringIO` or just split by newline:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

s = """10103;Baldwin, C;SFEN
10115;Wyatt, X;SFEN
10172;Forbes, I;SFEN
10175;Erickson, D;SFEN
10183;Chapman, O;SFEN
11399;Cordova, I;SYEN
11461;Wright, U;SYEN
11658;Kelly, P;SYEN
11714;Morton, A;SYEN
11788;Fuller, E;SYEN"""

reader = csv.reader(s.split('\n'), delimiter=';')
#or
reader = csv.reader(StringIO(s), delimiter=';')
for line in reader:
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
['10103', 'Baldwin, C', 'SFEN']
['10115', 'Wyatt, X', 'SFEN']
['10172', 'Forbes, I', 'SFEN']
['10175', 'Erickson, D', 'SFEN']
['10183', 'Chapman, O', 'SFEN']
['11399', 'Cordova, I', 'SYEN']
['11461', 'Wright, U', 'SYEN']
['11658', 'Kelly, P', 'SYEN']
['11714', 'Morton, A', 'SYEN']
['11788', 'Fuller, E', 'SYEN']
```