# Read certain part of a line/string

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to read a certain part of a string using python, but I can't seem to figure it out, and nobody has the solution I'm looking for.

I have multiple lines formatted similarly to this:

`1235:9875:0.1234`

Its separated with colons, but the thing is that the length of the line varies, so only reading a certain amount of characters wont work.

Anyone have any idea how to do this? I really need to know this and I hope that this can help other people in the future.

Comment: What part of the string do you need to read? You can do `str.split(':')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a string by a delimiter in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475251/split-a-string-by-a-delimiter-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the values into array as strings:

```py
test_str = "1235:9875:0.1234"
number_str_arr = test_str.split(":")  # ['1235', '9875', '0.1234']
```

Saving them as floats instead of strings (maybe what you want?)

```py
number_arr = [float(num) for num in number_str_arr]  # [1235.0, 9875.0, 0.1234]
```

How to access certain values:

```py
first_num = number_arr[0]  # 1235.0
last_num = number_arr[-1]  # 0.1234
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was initially looking for.