# Returning name of file after looping through directory

Tags: python

I am trying to return a portion of the file name after using os.scandir to loop through all .txt files. I'm taking a directory, searching through each text file within the directory for certain words, pulling the section that those words are found in, and then printing. While that portion works, I need to add the file name that the portion of text was found in. Something like  HD 354950 : supply chain issues were found with garden gnomes.

Below is the working code for just returning the information from within the texts -

```
dict = []
linenumber = 0
pattern = re.compile(r"\bsupply|finance\b", re.IGNORECASE)

for filename in os.scandir(directory):
    if filename.path.endswith(".txt"):
        f = open(filename, encoding = 'utf-8')
            lines = f.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                linenumber += 1
                if pattern.search(line) != None:
                    dict.append((linenumber, line.rstrip('\n')))
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

when the text is returned I want to be able to pull the name of the file that the text was found alongside the text itself. The filename is typically - HD_0000354950_10Q_20200503_Item1A_excerpt.txt and I want to return HD 354950.

I would like to join this with the output of what is returned when

```
for d in dict:
   print(filenamepieces, ":" + d[1])
```

where 'filenamepieces' is the file that the text tidbit is taken from

Comment: What are the file names? Which portion do you want to return?

Comment: It's possible. Please use the documentation or online tutorials to get a direction

Comment: @mkrieger1 Just a tidbit of the file name. Updated my original post

Comment: @Justlearnedit can you provide the link?

Comment: You can just split the string on `_`, take the first two items, and convert the second item to an integer.

Comment: @mkrieger1 whats posted is the extent of most of my Python knowledge, if you have a moment could you show me what that would look like py wise?

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475251/split-a-string-by-a-delimiter-in-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int

Comment: @mkrieger1 I see, but how do I implement that so each return generates the file name?

Comment: @mkrieger1 please see help below

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using `split()` and converting the string to `int`:

```
fileName = "HD_0000354950_10Q_20200503_Item1A_excerpt.txt" # The name of the file

splitFile = fileName.split("_") # Splits the file name with underscores (_) into sections 
index1 = splitFile[0] # Gets the name at the first index
index2 = splitFile[1] # Gets the name at the second index
index2 = int(index2) # Converts the second name into an int to remove the unnecessary zeros

finale = f"{index1} {index2}" # Final string
print(finale) # Prints the final string

# Program outputs : HD 354950
```

Comment: I'm receiving an error that nt.DirEntry object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: You need to convert it into a string before you can split it, like so: `str()`

Comment: receiving the same error - not sure its because I'm pulling in a list of files in the (directory) and it won't split on that. I don't have the ability to set a specific file to a variable

Comment: I tried splitting on the directory and that works but its one level higher than I need to be - hope that makes sense

Comment: You can add all the names to an array and iterate through each one that way.

Comment: You'll need to provide me with your code so I can help.

Comment: new user so I cant use the chat function. What do you need me to post?

Comment: Upload it to [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com) and send a link.