# How to split whole text to sentence pieces (parts) by python

Tags: python, pandas

**I need to split whole text to 4 parts.**

for example:

> AAAA: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAA. BBBB:
> BBBBBBBBBB BBBBBBBBBBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBBB. CCCC: CCCCCCC CCCCC CCCCCC
> CCCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCCC CCCCC. DDDD: DDDDDDDDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDDDDDDDD
> DDDDDDDDDD DDDDDDDDDDD.

**To**

> AAAA:  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAA.

> BBBB: BBBBBBBBBB BBBBBBBBBBBBB BBBBBBBBB BBBBBBB.

> CCCC:  CCCCCCC CCCCC CCCCCC CCCCCCCCCCC CCCC CCCC CCCCC.

> DDDD:  DDDDDDDDDD DDDDDDDDD DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD DDDDDDDDDDD.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a string by a delimiter in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475251/split-a-string-by-a-delimiter-in-python)

Comment: I'm sure you might have tried something? Please add that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python string function split with the argument of dot would lead to what you wish for.

You can also specify myStr.split("./r/n") to see where you have a dot that followed by a line down or two /r/n for doble line separation.