# Selecting specific row and columns from several files to create a new file

Tags: python

I'm very new to python so I have no idea how to even start this.

I have several TFS files and I need to read them and create a new file with a specific row and column from the other files.

Ex:

file 1:

```
x 1 # A
y 2 % B
z 3 * C
```

file 2:

```
x1 4 # A
y1 5 % B
z1 6 * C
```

file 3:

```
x2 7 # A
y2 8 % B
z2 9 * C
```

Expected output file:

```
y 2 B
y1 5 B
y2 8 B
```

(row 1 and columns 0, 1, 3 from all files)

Comment: break the problem down into steps and work out how to do each step.  you need to: open a file, read a specific line from the file (then you can google how to do that e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081836/how-to-read-specific-lines-from-a-file-by-line-number) then when you have the line you want you need to split it into columns (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475251/split-a-string-by-a-delimiter-in-python) and get just the column values you want, then write those values to the output file (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use the built-in [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) method:

```
result = []
row = 1
cols = [0, 1, 3]

files = ["file1.tfs", "file2.tfs", "file3.tfs"]

for file in files:
    with open(file) as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            if i == row:
                result.append(" ".join(char for j, char in enumerate(line.split()) if j in cols))
                break

print("\n".join(result))
```

Output:

```
y 2 B
y1 5 B
y2 8 B
```

For convenience in testing out this code, I replaced the files with lists of strings here:

```
result = []
row = 1
cols = [0, 1, 3]

fs = [
    ["x 1 # A", "y 2 % B", "z 3 * C"],
    ["x1 4 # A", "y1 5 % B", "z1 6 * C"],
    ["x2 7 # A", "y2 8 % B", "z2 9 * C"]
]

for f in fs:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i == row:
            result.append(" ".join(char for j, char in enumerate(line.split()) if j in cols))
            break

print("\n".join(result))
```

Output:

```
y 2 B
y1 5 B
y2 8 B
```