# How to get a specific numeric or any element from a string - Python?

Tags: python

Here I have a string.

```py
word = '10-7-2022 product_id:10 order_id:2 cost:500'
```

Here, I need to extract only the product_id's and order_id's value which is after ':'.
Kindly let me know how to make it happen.

Comment: are space between the date & product_id and product_id & order_id?

Comment: Use the `str.split` method. `word` is a sequence of space-separated strings; following the date, you have a sequence of `:`-separated key/value pairs.

Comment: You can achieve it by using `split`, refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475251/split-a-string-by-a-delimiter-in-python

Comment: if the id will always be in the same position (In this example right after the first `product_id:`, use `split`. Otherwise, regex might be better.

Comment: What did you try already? Are you familiar with [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and/or [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One other method is to use regex with named groups:

```
import re
reg = re.compile(r"(?P<product_id>(?<=product_id:)\d+).*(?P<order_id>(?<=order_id:)\d+)")
word = '10-7-2022 product_id:10 order_id:2 cost:500'
result = reg.search(word)
result.group('product_id')
result.group('order_id')
```

If not every string contain `product_id:` or `order_id:` then you can create a more general regex, and test if there is a result.

EDIT

Also getting the date, assuming that it would always be in the order of d-m-y with or without leading zeros:

```
import re
reg = re.compile(r"(?P<date>\d+-\d+-\d+).*(?P<product_id>(?<=product_id:)\d+).*(?P<order_id>(?<=order_id:)\d+)")
word = '10-7-2022 product_id:10 order_id:2 cost:500'
result = reg.search(word)
result.group('date')
```

You can also get a datetime object:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime(result.group('date'), r'%d-%m-%Y')
>>> datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 10, 0, 0)
```

Comment: @PrabhasKumar Yes that is true, but As we said before, using regex makes it possible to use more general expressions. For example when the string later also contains an `client_id:` for example. But again, if you know the exact input there are faster methods. But it depends on the amount of data  you want to process to determine if the performance is significant. In my opinion both methods have their use cases.

Comment: Also if I may be so blunt, as long as one is using `python`, performance is not the most important thing in mind, I think it is save to say that when using python the simplicity is more important.