# Python split string into multiple string

Tags: python, string, list, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split string into a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/split-string-into-a-list-in-python)

I have a string with a lot of part-strings

```
>>> s = 'str1, str2, str3, str4'
```

now I have a function like following

```
>>> def f(*args):
        print(args)
```

what I need, is to split my string into multiple strings, so that my function prints something like this

```
>>> f(s)
('str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4')
```

Has someone an idea, how I can perform this?

- edit:
  I did not searched a function to split a string into an array of Strings.

This is what i searched for.

```
>>> s = s.split(', ')
>>> f(*s)
('str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4')
```

Comment: I'm puzzled by questions like this. Everyone has plenty of basic doubts when starting with a new language, but did you try searching for 'python split string' in your search engine of choice or this site's search feature?

Comment: @Marcin Sorry, i think i did not explained my problem enough. I didn't search a function, to split a string into an array of strings. I needed a split of a string, to get multiple Strings, without any array.

Thats the code, which do what i searched for.
`def f(*args):
    print(args)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = 'str1, str2, str3, str4'
    f(*(s.split(', ')))
`

Comment: @Marcin I have a function, which is defined by following code and i don't want to change this code.

`def dirEntries(fileList, subdir=False, *args):
    '''Example usage: fileList = dirEntries(r'H:\TEMP', False, 'txt', 'py')
 Only files with 'txt' and 'py' extensions will be added to the list.
 Example usage: fileList = dirEntries(r'H:\TEMP', True)'''`

Comment: @Marcin I know, that this place is not the right place to discuss. I never said, that i dislike lists. I only searched for a solution of my problem and after i found it, i would present the solution here.

Answer (score 27):

You can split a string by using `split()`. The syntax is as follows...

`stringtosplit.split('whattosplitat')`

To split your example at every comma and space, it would be:

```
s = 'str1, str2, str3, str4'
s.split(', ')
```

Answer (score 10):

A bit of google would have found this..

```
string = 'the quick brown fox'
splitString = string.split()

...

['the','quick','brown','fox']
```

Comment: The default delimiter is `<space>`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
s = 'str1, str2, str3, str4'
print s.split(',')
```

Comment: Would someone care explaining why I was downvoted so that I could learn from my mistakes?

Comment: No explication, AND answering a help vampire.