# how to split a python string

Tags: python

I have a python function that returns the following:

```
result = myfunction()
result will be e.g. "192.168.200.123, 02/12/2013 13:59:42, 02/12/2013 13:59:42"
```

i.e. a string that contains 3 values separated by commas.

How do I split this string into 3 new variables??

Comment: Should you be in control of that python function, it might be nice to just return the three values as a tuple rather than a string (`return (a, b, c)`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703512/python-split-string-into-multiple-string/9703580

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s = "192.168.200.123, 02/12/2013 13:59:42, 02/12/2013 13:59:42"
>>> n = [e.strip() for e in s.split(',')]
>>> print n
['192.168.200.123', '02/12/2013 13:59:42', '02/12/2013 13:59:42']
```

`n` is now a list with three elements. If you know your string will be split into exactly three variables and you want to name them, use this:

```
a, b, c = [e.strip() for e in s.split(',')]
```

The `strip` is used to remove unwanted spaces before/after strings.

Answer (score 2):

Use the split function:

```
my_string = #Contains ','
split_array = my_string.split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = myfunction()
result will be e.g. "192.168.200.123, 02/12/2013 13:59:42, 02/12/2013 13:59:42"
```

Two ways to solve this:

In `myfunction()`, return a `list` or a `tuple`: `return (a, b, c)` or return `[a, b, c]`.

Or, you can use the [`s.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) function:

```
result = my_function()
results = result.split(',')
```

You can simplify this further like such:

```
result = my_function().split(',')
```