# How to make a file that looks like a list into a list?

Tags: python, list, file, format

In my code I have a list called euler22.txt:

```
with open('euler22.txt') as f:
    name_list = f.read().splitlines()
```

`euler22.text` is a long file, but I'll post the first 5 values in it:

```
"MARY","PATRICIA","LINDA","BARBARA","ELIZABETH"
```

As you can see, it's structured as a list, but when I run the code the way I have it, it says that the length of `name_list` is only 1 - whereas I want it to be 500 (the length of the list). How can I make my code open this file as a list that is the length of how it's structured in the file?

Comment: Split on comma?

Comment: Is the file one long line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python split string into multiple string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703512/python-split-string-into-multiple-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `split` method:

```py
with open('euler22.txt') as f:
    name_list = f.read().split(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `csv` module to load the data to a list:

```
import csv

data = []
with open('<your file.txt>', 'r') as f_in:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for line in reader:
        data.extend(line)
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
['MARY', 'PATRICIA', 'LINDA', 'BARBARA', 'ELIZABETH']
```

---

Or:

If the data is only on one line you can try to use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
from ast import literal_eval
data = literal_eval('[' + open('<your file.txt>', 'r').read() + ']')
```

Answer (score 0):

The file looks like a CSV with many columns and just one row. You can use the csv module to parse it.

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('euler22.txt') as fp:
...     names = next(csv.reader(fp))
... 
>>> names
['MARY', 'PATRICIA', 'LINDA', 'BARBARA', 'ELIZABETH']
>>> len(names)
5
```