# In Python, is there a way to capture the following YYYYMMDD-N from a URL

Tags: python, string

I am looking for a way to capture the following with either a regular expression or a built-in function in Python.

From `/url-path/YYYYMMDD-N/url-path-cont` I only need `YYYYMMDD-N`. Sometimes the `-N` is present and sometimes it is not. I have tried various methods but so far all my attempts either stop at `YYYMMDD` or capture part of `/url-path-cont`.

I would like to capture only the `YYYYMMDD-N` with the `-N` as optional whenever present.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python split string into multiple string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703512/python-split-string-into-multiple-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably better ways of doing this, but as long as there's always the same amount of `/` then you could use the split method:

```
url_path = "/url-path/YYYYMMDD-N/url-path-cont"
date_only = url_path.split("/")[2]
print(date_only)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, the OP asked specifically for a regular expression (regex)

Comment: @Luke Thank you. Your solution worked perfectly. That is the result I was looking for.

Comment: Reword your question then, and remove the term regex, if this is the answer your looking for.

Comment: @Jared I will edit my question so that it's not specific to regular expressions and to not cause confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regular expression that will extract the date from a string.

```
>>> import re
>>> url = "url-path/YYYYMMDD-N/url-path-cont"
>>> re.compile(r"/(\w+-?\w?)/").search(url).group(1)
'YYYYMMDD-N'
>>>
```