# put the words of a line in a array/list that can be referenced by an index using Python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split string into a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/split-string-into-a-list-in-python)

I have a text text file,  2011 2012 332 1972 ...

I need to access the words of this line (stored in a text file) using some index, could be an array, like a[] should contain contents of a line , where every element of a[] should be a word. Now, when I run a for loop I can access the words of the a[] using some index. like a[0],a[1].
Please suggest some ways...

Answer (score -1):

Use code like this:

```
fh = open("foo")
line = fh.readline()
words = line.split()
```

Comment: I have copied the contents of a read file A into another file B by running a for loop , but how will i be able to retrieve the different words/ strings of a line (assuming for now i just a line in that file)so that i can format it and then write in file B again.