# python - splitting a string in a list into multiple strings

Tags: python

i have a list

```
strings = ['abc efg hijklmn aaaaa']
```

and I am trying to split that into a list of multiple strings:

```
strings = ['abc', 'efg', 'hijklmn', 'aaaaa']
```

how do I go about doing this? seems very trivial

Comment: Seriously? Have you ever heard of google? I think 2 minutes search there would have gotten you an answer...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split string into a list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/split-string-into-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strings = ['abc efg hijklmn aaaaa']
strings = strings[0].split()
```

Comment: why the downvote downvoter? don'y worry some people go on random down-voting runs....

Comment: Awesome! didn't know too much about split() :)

Answer (score 2):

This will work even if there are more strings in the original list.

```
strings = ['abc efg hijklmn aaaaa', 'abc efg hijklmn aaaaa']
print [item for current in strings for item in current.split()]
```

Comment: I honestly have no idea why the one with 3 upvotes got 3 upvotes, what is the point in having a string in a list if there's one string!

Comment: and @AlecTeal you don't upvote this? the most perfect solution....

Comment: @KDawG I don't vote on competing answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
otherlist = []
for thing in strings:
    otherlist.extend(thing.split(" "))
strings = otherlist
```