# How to split a string input and append to a list? Python

Tags: python, string, input, append

I want to ask the user what foods they have ate, then split that input up into a list.  Right now, the code is spitting out just empty brackets.

Also, this is my first post on here, so I apologize in advance for any formating errors.

```
list_of_food = []


def split_food(input):

    #split the input
    words = input.split()

    for i in words:
        list_of_food = list_of_food.append(i)

print list_of_food
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Next time try to show what you've tried.

Comment: Looks like OP tried that code there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-list)

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in words:
    list_of_food = list_of_food.append(i)
```

You should change this just to

```
for i in words:
    list_of_food.append(i)
```

For two different reasons. First, `list.append()` is an in-place operator, so you don't need to worry about reassigning your list when you use it. Second, when you're trying to use a global variable inside a function, you either need to declare it as `global` or never assign to it. Otherwise, the only thing you'll be doing is modifying a local. This is what you're probably trying to do with your function.

```
def split_food(input):

    global list_of_food

    #split the input
    words = input.split()

    for i in words:
        list_of_food.append(i)
```

However, because you shouldn't use globals unless absolutely necessary (it's not a great practice), this is the best method:

```
def split_food(input, food_list):

    #split the input
    words = input.split()

    for i in words:
        food_list.append(i)

    return food_list
```

Comment: Or better, skip the for loop and use `list_of_food.extend(words)`.

Comment: There's no need for the list_of_food at all is there?  words will be a list as soon as you do the split.

Comment: @Robert Moskal if you want to return at all that is, append will modify your list anyway

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> text = "What can I say about this place. The staff of these restaurants is nice and the eggplant is not bad.'
>>> txt1 = text.split('.')
>>> txt2 = [line.split() for line in txt1]
>>> new_list = []
>>> for i in range(0, len(txt2)):
        l1 = txt2[i]
        for w in l1:
          new_list.append(w)
print(new_list)
```

Comment: `split()`already returns a list, so you iterate over one list to copy element by element to another list

Answer (score 1):

Use the "extend" keyword. This aggregates two lists together.

```
list_of_food = []


def split_food(input):

    #split the input
    words = input.split()
    list_of_food.extend(words)

print list_of_food
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_food = []

def split_food(input):   
    #split the input
    words = input.split()    
    for i in words:
        list_of_food = list_of_food.append(i)

print(list_of_food)
```