# Python split a string into mutiple sub-strings

Tags: python, split

Could some one help me to fix a long question for me.
 I wanna split a long string into multiple sub-strings.
Like this:

```
a= 1000 0.22222 aa bb 22 55 44 77 10 1.0
a1= 1000
a2= bb 22 55
a3= 77 10 1.0
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried anything yourself? Take a look at [split string into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/split-string-into-a-list-in-python)

Comment: What exactly is the pattern you're trying to follow here?

Comment: Thank all of you. In fact, I need a replace function for my script. Here,I just ask how to do split first. I have got the function by searching on stackoverflow. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
splited = a.split(' ')
print splited[0]
print splited[3:6]
print splited[-3:]
```

the output

http://testedanswers.com/questions/-JtQBz4MWfJYfmk00RZK