# (Python 2.7 IDE) Why wont .split() work in a function?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, split

When i just make a variable,i get this. please see below

```
a = 'a d c'
a
'a d c'
a.split()
['a', 'd', 'c']
```

When i make a function, i get this. please see below

```
def x():
    a = 'abc ash avs'
    a.split()
    print a

x()
abc ash avs
```

Comment: split() does not split in place, it returns a list: words = a.split()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split string into a list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/split-string-into-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `split()` split your string based on whitespace when you don't pass a specific argument to it. So in your function it split `'abc ash avs'` based on spaces.

If you want the characters you can use `list` function.

```
>>> a = 'abc ash avs'
>>> list(a)
['a', 'b', 'c', ' ', 'a', 's', 'h', ' ', 'a', 'v', 's']
```

And if you want alphabetical characters you can use a list comprehension to get them :

```
>>> [i for i in a if i.isalpha()]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 's', 'h', 'a', 'v', 's']
```

Comment: So python knows the alphabet like it can "sort" numbers?

Comment: @corbshum Sorry I didn't get you can you explain more!

Comment: @corbshum Python does know how to sort letters alphabetically, but I think you misunderstood that part of the answer. Kasramvd was showing you how to make a list of the characters that are letters (ie. Alphabetical) while leaving out spaces. It seems like Kasra thought you wanted a list of every letter, not a list split by spaces.

Comment: Sorry i did miss read it and deleted the comment ha not quick enough though! I learned something new though and it makes sense so thank you for your time and helo

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Good explain but already I said that for getting a list of all letters OP can use `list()` function!

Comment: @corbshum Its OK, welcome. fortunately  SuperBiasedMan added some explain!

Answer (score 2):

`split()` returns a list of the words in the string you pass it. You are not updating the variable `a` when calling it in your function.

```
def x():
    a = 'abc ash avs'
    a = a.split()
    print a
```

Comment: Thanks a lot makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You're not modifying the `a` string itself since Python strings are immutable. Because you're in the interpreter it will print what a function returns. That's why you get the list printed on screen there. But the `x` function doesn't return the split list, merely prints `a`.

You'll see your expected result if you switch to this:

```
def x():
    a = 'abc ash avs'
    print a.split()
```

And you can see what I mean about `a` not being modified with this:

```
a = 'a d c'
a
'a d c'
a.split()
['a', 'd', 'c']
a
'a d c'
```

Comment: Thank you this is what i just figured out so thanks for confirming so quickly!