# Converting string of numbers to tuple of numbers

Tags: python

I have a string like this:

```
'5100387,  54.799831647418,  -4.147024550067,  22.466648807633'
```

I want to get a tuple from it:

```
(5100387,  54.799831647418,  -4.147024550067,  22.466648807633)
```

How to do it?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/split-string-into-a-list-in-python and [str.split method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` on commas and use a generator expression to convert each item to `float`, then create a `tuple` from that.

```
>>> tuple(float(i) for i in s.split(','))
(5100387.0, 54.799831647418, -4.147024550067, 22.466648807633)
```

Similarly `map` can do the same thing

```
>>> tuple(map(float, s.split(',')))
(5100387.0, 54.799831647418, -4.147024550067, 22.466648807633)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string contains a valid tuple literal. You could give [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) a try:

```
In [1]: import ast

In [2]: ast.literal_eval('5100387, 54.799831647418, -4.147024550067, 22.466648807633')
Out[2]: (5100387, 54.799831647418, -4.147024550067, 22.466648807633)
```

or split by `', '` and convert each element of the list to float (or something else):

```
In [4]: tuple(map(float, s.split(', ')))
Out[4]: (5100387.0, 54.799831647418, -4.147024550067, 22.466648807633)
```