# python data array string convert to list

Tags: python, list

Now I have a string like this：

```
data = "[[1,'00007',0.19],[2,'00008',0.29],[3,'00009',0.49],[4,'00010',0.59]]"

print(type(data))

<class 'str'>
```

in python this is like data array out,but it is a string, now I want convert this string to the real data array  `<class 'list'>` , How should I do this

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/split-string-into-a-list-in-python for inspiration.

Comment: how do you get `data` ? maybe you shouldn't convert array to string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
eval(data)
```

to parse its content.

Comment: use of `eval` is considered bad

Comment: It's unsafe, there you're right. Simply depends on the application - if used in a little script without user interaction it should not be a problem, I'd say.

Comment: Just wanted to add it there since the OP should know when to use it :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html): as the documentation says-

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded
> string containing a Python literal or container display.
>
> The string or
> node provided may only consist of the following Python literal
> structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and
> None.

```
>>> import ast

>>> data = "[[1,'00007',0.19],[2,'00008',0.29],[3,'00009',0.49],[4,'00010',0.59]]"
>>> ast.literal_eval(data)
[[1, '00007', 0.19], [2, '00008', 0.29], [3, '00009', 0.49], [4, '00010', 0.59]]

>>> print(type(ast.literal_eval(data)))
>>> <type 'list'>
```

Avoid using `eval` unless truly needed. Details [at](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Answer (score 0):

Following on from your definition of data:

```
data_list = data.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("'","").split(",")
new_list = [data_list[x:x+3] for x in range(0, len(data_list), 3)]
```

Though everything in the result is now a string.