# How to split the string in python

Tags: python

How to split the string here I having this format

> position:absolute;top:188.97638px;left:642.519692px;font-size:10.0px;font-family:Ubuntu
>   Mono;width:25%;float:left

. I need like this

```
position:absolute;
top:188.97638px;
left:642.519692px;
font-size:10.0px;
font-family:Ubuntu Mono;
width:25%;
float:left
```

How to get this.

Comment: Did you try `str.split(";")`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string into a list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/split-string-into-a-list-in-python)

Comment: @thefourtheye I think replacing `';'` with `';\n'` is actually what he wants, or at least splitting and re-appending the semi-colon.

Comment: `for i in str.split(";"): print(i + ';')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> mystring = "position:absolute;top:188.97638px;left:642.519692px;font-size:10.0px;font-family:Ubuntu Mono;width:25%;float:left"
>>> result = [x + ";" for x in mystring.split(";")]                             
>>> print '\n'.join(result)
```

Output:

```
position:absolute;
top:188.97638px;
left:642.519692px;
font-size:10.0px;
font-family:Ubuntu Mono;
width:25%;
float:left;
```

If you really have to get rid of the last part's semi colon:

```
result[-1] = result[-1][:-1]
```