# How do I separate a each text file line into a separate lists?

Tags: python, list

say i have a text file which contains the following:

```
Bob 15 M
John 16 M
Jen 15 F
```

How do I put it into a list so that the list values are:

```
listOne = ['Bob', '15', 'M']
listTwo = ['John', '16', 'M']
listThree = ['Jen', '15', 'F']
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string into a list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/split-string-into-a-list-in-python)

Comment: @PeterWood ya, forgeted.

Comment: @Tim  I want each line to be a new list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just split it and unpack it

```
bob, john, jen = [a.split() for a in open(file)]
```

Comment: very good point. though it would be garbage collected and closed but we cant always depend on the interpreter to do that

Comment: In CPython, it would usually be immediately garbage-collected; in other Python implementation, it might stay around for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Use open file and split():

```
with open('text.txt') as f:
    strings = f.readlines()
    data = [string.split() for string in strings]
```

Comment: No need for strings.  Just iterate over the file object.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply [**`string.split`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) to each line in the file:

```
import string

with open('text.txt') as text:
    result = map(string.split, text)
```

With Python 3, you need to materialise the `map`, otherwise the file doesn't get read before it's closed:

```
    result = list(map(string.split, text))
```

However, `string.split` is deprecated and would only apply to `str` objects, not `unicode`. A more general solution is to create a list comprehension:

```
    result = [line.split() for line in text]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
with open('text.txt') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()        # Creates a list of lines
    for line in lines:
        line = line.split()         # Split each line into list of "words"
```

This gives you a nested list which is probably sensible. If you desperately want 3 lists, use this:

```
evalvar = ""
count = 0
for line in lines:
    count += 1
    evalvar += "list"+str(count)+" = "+str(line)+";"
exec(evalvar)                                         # Runs the evalvar which has
                                                      # code in it.
```