# How to display only the names of the users when opening /etc/group in Python?

Tags: python, list, grep

This is my code:

```
grouplist = open("/etc/group" , "r")
with grouplist as f2:
    with open("group" , "w+") as f1:
    f1.write(f2.read())
    f1.seek(0,0)
    command = f1.read()
    print
    print command
```

What command can I use to make it display only the names of the users without the ":x:1000:"

Comment: Do not understand, how `grep` and `debian` tags are involved. Do you want solution with `python`?

Comment: I'd recommend using the [`grp` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/grp.html) in Python's standard library rather than parsing `/etc/group` directly.

Comment: I use python on debian and I need to use some sort of grep inthis command.
Also I need to do this without using any modules.

Comment: "I need to do this without using any modules" – I can't see any valid reason for this requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost achieved the target. With a little fix in your code, here is the solution.

```
 with open("/etc/group" , "r") as source:
    with open("./group" , "w+") as destination:
        destination.write(source.read())
        source.seek(0,0)
        for user in source.readlines():
            print user[: user.index(':')]
```

Nevertheless, this only show the names, but still copy the original file.

This way you write only the names in the new file.

```
with open("/etc/group" , "r") as source:
    with open("./group" , "w+") as destination:
        for user in source.readlines():
            u = user[: user.index(':')]
            destination.write('%s\n' % u)
            print u
```

Comment: Thanks that was super helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

How about `split()` [[1]](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/split-string-into-a-list-in-python)

```
with open("/etc/group" , "r") as f2:
   for line in f2:
       list1=line.split(str=":")
       print list1[0]
```

Comment: How come it only works for the first line in the file? as in it only works for "root"

Comment: You should add a cycle. I answered exactly the question "What command can I use to make it display only the names of the users without the ":x:1000:""