# How do I split an element of a list into multiple elements in python 3?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, arraylist, element

I want to know how to split a singular element of my list into multiple different elements. For example:

```
list=['My phone is cracked']
```

I want to make it into this:

```
list=['My','phone','is','cracked']
```

Comment: `list[0].split()` / `[x for s in list for x in s.split()]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string into a list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/split-string-into-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

```
list=['My phone is cracked']
list = list[0].split(" ")
print(list)
```

This will print your desired output.
the reason why there is a `[0]` after the `list` is because `split` only works on strings so you will have to take out the first value in the array and that will treat it like an array.
Hope this helps!:)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the ask is to iterate through the list and split the element into multiple elements using ' ' if exists, else element as is.

So

> ['My phone is cracked', 'new phone', 'collection']

becomes

> ['My', 'phone', 'is', 'cracked', 'new', 'phone', 'collection']

This is how you can do that:

```
list1 = ['My phone is cracked', 'new phone', 'collection']
new_list1 = [y for x in list1 for y in x.split(' ')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split() method (https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

`list[0].split()`