# python slicing string by pointing special character

Tags: python, string

I have some strings that have been divided into 2 parts by **`-`** sign, for example:

```
s = 'Teh-Iran'
```

I want to cut the string to pick up the first parts only, for example the word `Teh`

The problem is that the length of first parts and the length of the second parts are not certain. So how can I slice them by pointing at `-` sign to use the first parts?

Comment: More useful answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/split-string-into-a-list-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go for the [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method of `str` type:

```
>>> "Teh-Iran".split('-')
['Teh', 'Iran']
>>> "Teh-Iran".split('-')[0]
'Teh'
>>>
```