# How to split a list of text into a list of words Python

Tags: python, list

I have this list:

```
["This is a set of words and it is not correct"]
```

I want to make it like this:

```
["This", "Is", "A"] ...
```

How do I do this

Comment: Do you want to split on arbitrary whitespace or just a single `" "`?

Comment: Please google this : "split a sentence into words"

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/split-string-into-a-list-in-python

Comment: You write some Python code.

Answer (score 3):

```
"This is a set of words and it is not correct".title().split()
```

output:

```
['This', 'Is', 'A', 'Set', 'Of', 'Words', 'And', 'It', 'Is', 'Not', 'Correct']
```

Comment: `str.title` is pretty cute.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```
a = "This is a set of words and it is not correct"
[i.capitalize() for i in a.split()]
```

if input is `list` as you mentioned in your question.

```
a = ["This is a set of words and it is not correct"]
[i.capitalize() for i in a[0].split()]
```

**Output**

> ['This', 'Is', 'A', 'Set', 'Of', 'Words', 'And', 'It', 'Is', 'Not',
>   'Correct']

Answer (score 0):

Use the `split()` method

```
>>> foo = ["This is a set of words and it is not correct"]
>>> foo[0].split()
['This', 'is', 'a', 'set', 'of', 'words', 'and', 'it', 'is', 'not', 'correct']
```