# split list by delimited in python

Tags: python, list, split

From a dict/list, how to split the list by \n. Eg:

```
In [1]: d = {'key1': 'value1\n   value2  \n value3\n'}

In [2]: d.values()
Out[2]: ['value1\n   value2  \n value3\n']
```

Desired output:

```
['value1', 'value2  ', 'value3']
```

I looked at existing examples but couldn't find this specific one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string into a list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/split-string-into-a-list-in-python)

Comment: Your desired output shows the string in the values array split by `\n` and then leading (but not trailing) whitespace stripped. Is the stripping of whitespace significant? If so, can you put that in the question? Also, can you give a better example of desired output such as eg when there is more than one entry in the original dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
d['key1'].split('\n')
```

Comment: This actually gives `['value1', '   value2  ', ' value3', '']` so you'd need to slice  off the last item if it's empty string.

Comment: Thanks I didn't realized d[k] outputs str (unlike d.values() that outputs list)!!

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want the values as a flat list? Something like this?

```
>>> {k: [x.strip() for x in v.splitlines()] for k, v in d.iteritems()}
{'key1': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']}
```

Comment: as BPL points out, remove `iter` from `iteritems` if you use Python3. Why he duplicated my answer, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

**Python 2.x**

```
d = {'key1': 'value1\n   value2  \n value3\n'}
print {k: [x.strip() for x in v.splitlines()] for k, v in d.iteritems()}
```

**Python 3.x**

```
d = {'key1': 'value1\n   value2  \n value3\n'}
print({k: [x.strip() for x in v.splitlines()] for k, v in d.items()})
```