# if allwords in title: match

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, matching, cpu-word

Using python3, i have a list of words like:
`['foot', 'stool', 'carpet']`

these lists vary in length from 1-6 or so. i have thousands and thousands of strings to check, and it is required to make sure that all three words are present in a title. where:
`'carpet stand upon the stool of foot balls.'`
is a correct match, as all the words are present here, even though they are out of order.

ive wondered about this for a long time, and the only thing i could think of was some sort of iteration like:

```
for word in list: if word in title: match!
```

but this give me results like `'carpet cleaner'` which is incorrect. i feel as though there is some sort of shortcut to do this, but i cant seem to figure it out without using excessive`list(), continue, break` or other methods/terminology that im not yet familiar with. etc etc.

Comment: Would you want `recarpeted footstool` to match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
words = ['foot', 'stool', 'carpet']
title = "carpet stand upon the stool of foot balls."

matches = all(word in title for word in words)
```

Or, inverse the logic with not [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and `not in`:

```
matches = not any(word not in title for word in words)
```

Comment: You might want to split if substrings should not be matched.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham. Also to avoid things like `recarpeted` from matching.

Comment: Good points, thanks! Nltk's *word tokenizer* might be a bit better option to split into words and handle all the punctuation.

Comment: Here's a simpler option that just strips the punctuation using vanilla Python: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17951315/2988730