# How to extract the text between a word and its next occurrence?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the following sample text:

```
mystr = r'''\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\title{\LaTeX}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
This is introduction paragraph
\section{Non-Introduction}
This is non-introduction paragraph
\section{Sample section}
This is sample section paragraph
\begin{itemize}
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
\end{itemize}
\end{document}'''
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to create a regex expression which will extract the following lines from `mystr`:

```
['This is introduction paragraph','This is non-introduction paragraph','    This is sample section paragraph\n \begin{itemize}\n\item Item 1\n\item Item 2\n\end{itemize}']
```

Comment: that what `split()` does. Why does it have to be a regex ?

Comment: Your example does not illustrate the question. "quick elephant" does not have an occurance of the word "a" after it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/split-string-into-a-list-in-python has more detailed description, but the answer above is correct...

Comment: Good job on the edit; this helps people understand what you're after. Have you attempted anything thus far to tackle this problem? It might help posting it if you have.

Answer (score 2):

For any reason you need to use regex. Perhaps the splitting string is more involved than just "a". The `re` module has a split function too:

```
import re
str_ = "a quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog than a quick elephant"


print(re.split(r'\s?\ba\b\s?',str_))

# ['', 'quick brown fox jumps over', 'lazy dog than', 'quick elephant']
```

**EDIT: expanded answer with the new information you provided...**

After your edit in which you write a better description of your problem and you include a text that looks like LaTeX, I think you need to extract those lines that do not start with a `\`, which are the latex commands. In other words, you need the lines with only text. Try the following, always using regular expressions:

```
import re

mystr = r'''\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\title{\LaTeX}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
This is introduction paragraph
\section{Non-Introduction}
This is non-introduction paragraph
\section{Sample section}
This is sample section paragraph
\end{document}'''

pattern = r"^[^\\]*\n"


matches = re.findall(pattern, mystr, flags=re.M)

print(matches)

# ['This is introduction paragraph\n', 'This is non-introduction paragraph\n', 'This is sample section paragraph\n']
```

Comment: Thanks you... But splitting won't solve my purpose. Sorry for the inability to write the question in full.

Comment: @RebhuJohymalyoJosh: OK, just try to explain it better, perhaps with a real example and code of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have edited the question. Kindly have a look at it.

Comment: @RebhuJohymalyoJosh: Check the edited answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey sorry for the trouble but that won't work either. I have updated the query again to give you a more detailed explaination.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split` method from `str`:

```
my_string = "a quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog than a quick elephant"
word = "a "
my_string.split(word)
```

Results in:

```
['', 'quick brown fox jumps over ', 'lazy dog than ', 'quick elephant']
```

**Note:** Don't use `str` as a variable name as it is a keyword in Python.

Comment: str is NOT a keyword in python. Its just a build in class. So technically there is no issue in using a str keyword

Comment: @RebhuJohymalyoJosh while you are right that it is not a keyword you are wrong in stating that there's no issue in using it. Using `str` as a name for your variable will mask the built-in `str` and might lead to unexpected issues in the long run. In short, *avoid using it*.

Comment: @Jose Sanchez: Your solution would give strange results, if you feed it with a word, that contains an "a" at the end, for example "a quick brown fox jumps over a lazy lama than a quick elephant". You could use " a " to split, if you would use " "+my_string