# How do you extract the word from "what does [word] mean" in a python string?

Tags: python

Is there a way to extract a *word* using the spaces around it like so:

```
string = 'what does blah mean?'
```

With prior knowledge of only there being "what does" and then the word and then "mean", how would one get the word?

Comment: try ``string.split()[2]``

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split string into a list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/split-string-into-a-list-in-python)

Comment: How would one use that for extracting the blah in this?

Comment: @jakevdp's suggestion already extracts `blah` from your sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As says https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split:

> string.split(s[, sep[, maxsplit]])
>
> Return a list of the words of the
>   string s. If the optional second argument sep is absent or None, the
>   words are separated by arbitrary strings of whitespace characters
>   (space, tab, newline, return, formfeed). If the second argument sep is
>   present and not None, it specifies a string to be used as the word
>   separator. The returned list will then have one more item than the
>   number of non-overlapping occurrences of the separator in the string.
>   If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit number of splits occur, and the
>   remainder of the string is returned as the final element of the list
>   (thus, the list will have at most maxsplit+1 elements). If maxsplit is
>   not specified or -1, then there is no limit on the number of splits
>   (all possible splits are made).
>
> The behavior of split on an empty string depends on the value of sep.
>   If sep is not specified, or specified as None, the result will be an
>   empty list. If sep is specified as any string, the result will be a
>   list containing one element which is an empty string.

So, you would use `string.split()[the_word_you_want-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to use a regular expression such as:

```
import re

test = re.compile(r"what does (.*?) mean", re.IGNORE_CASE)
```

then find all in your input and use the `[1]` element from each match.