# Slicing in Python, one part of string

Tags: python, slice

I have one challenge to complete!

I have one form that takes the email typed, like this:
(Always in this format)
example: bianca.mary@john.com

I need to get the first part (bianca) before '.' and put this in one label and in another label, put the second part (mary)

Could you help me?

Comment: share your code first, what you have tried so far

Comment: Use string `split`. This looks like a homework question, so I'll just point you in the right direction:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dotPoint = text.index(".")
atPoint = text.index("@")
firstPart = text[0:dotPoint]
secondPart = text[dotPoint+1:atPoint]
print firstPart
print secondPart
```

This will output

```
bianca
mary
```

There you go. On Python 2.7 :)

Comment: Ownn...Thanks,  this will help me a lot...let me ask, where in Django i put this? Views.py?

Comment: You can put it anywhere that you have your string to split up.