# Spliting a sentence in python using iteration

Tags: python-3.x, programming-languages

I have a challenge in my class that is to split a sentence into a list of separate words using iteration. I can't use any .split functions. Anybody had any ideas?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Tried Googling?

Comment: A simple search for "[python]split a sentence" shows this has already been answered.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-list) may help.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald, the OP can't use `.split()` and nearly all of the many answers on that page use `.split()`.  [One that doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/744046/5771269) addresses natural language issues which are likely to come up as soon as a simple solution is tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence = 'how now brown cow'
words = []
wordStartIndex = 0
for i in range(0,len(sentence)):
    if sentence[i:i+1] == ' ':
        if i > wordStartIndex:
            words.append(sentence[wordStartIndex:i])
            wordStartIndex = i + 1
if i > wordStartIndex:
    words.append(sentence[wordStartIndex:len(sentence)])
for w in words:
    print('word = ' + w)
```

Needs tweaking for leading spaces or multiple spaces or punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

I never miss an opportunity to drag out `itertools.groupby()`:

```
from itertools import groupby

sentence = 'How now brown cow?'

words = []

for isalpha, characters in groupby(sentence, str.isalpha):
    if isalpha:  # characters are letters
        words.append(''.join(characters))

print(words)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
['How', 'now', 'brown', 'cow']
%
```

Now go back and define what you mean by 'word', e.g. what do you want to do about hyphens, apostrophes, etc.