# How to split() each entry in a list into a new csv column

Tags: python, list, split

I have the following code which is reading a list of folders from a directory, and dumping them into a csv file.

```
import os, csv

mylist = os.listdir("M:/")

with open("output.csv", 'w') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, lineterminator='\n')
    wr.writerows(([row] for row in mylist))
```

Which is working well. The folders in the directory are all named using this format:

```
abc_123456
```

And the output I'm trying to get is:

```
abc, 123456
def, 789012
```

etc.

I know that I need to use split() but I can't work out where it needs to go

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-list)

Comment: maybe `wr.writerows(row.split("_") for row in mylist)`?

Comment: can you show an example of the format of the output.csv file?

Comment: @Cyzanfar Output is already in the question

Comment: @Cyzanfar It's opened in `w` mode... The file is empty. The expected output is clearly stated

Comment: Right, didn't see that thanks @cricket_007

Comment: @OzgurVatansever that's done it it perfectly, thank you. I was trying to overcomplicate it by including [row].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `row = "abc_123456"`, you need to split that on `"_"`

`[row]` is making a list of one string that you are writing as the row.

`row.split("_")` is how you would split the data. This returns a list already, so no need for `[row.split("_")]`, for example

If you want to have `", "` as the delimiter rather than **only** a comma, then you need to add that to the writer.

```
wr = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter=', ', lineterminator='\n')
wr.writerows(row.split('_') for row in mylist)
```

Comment: Yeah, didn't see that

Comment: "This returns a list already, so no need for [row.split("_")], for example"

This was the mistake I was making. Thank you for the explanation as to why that's not needed.

Answer (score 2):

As @OzgurVatansever stated in the comment you can simply split on `"_"`:

```
import os, csv
mylist = os.listdir("M:/")

with open("output.csv", 'w') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, lineterminator='\n')
    wr.writerows(row.split("_") for row in mylist)
```

Hope that helps. Thanks @OzgurVatansever.