# How can I print half of object's or function's name?

Tags: python, function, object, printing

I try to create an ai game, how can I print chosen objects or function's name only before the '_'? For example:

```
players = [random_player, ai_player]
player_number= input('Determine first player Random(0) or AI(1):')
player_number2= input('Determine second player Random (0) or AI (1):')
player_array=[players[int(player_number)], players[int(player_number2)]]

# this is the wrong format I know.
print(' The game begins with {0} vs {1}'.format((player_array[0]), (player_array[1]))
```

output must be like that
:

```
The game begins with random vs ai
```

Comment: Did you try `split("_")`?

Comment: Do you mean should I create an array ['random', 'player', 'ai', 'player'] ?

Comment: More specificially, `"random_player".split("_")[0]` will give you what you are looking for. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-list)

Comment: But this is an object so does it make difference?

Comment: well you never said it was an object / not in your code

Comment: And I do not know which is will be called? so I cannot use 'random_player' as a code

Comment: Does `random_player` have its own `__str__` or `__repr__` method? If so, modify it to report the name without the second part. If not, add one of those methods.