# count total in a list python by split

Tags: python, split

I like to know how to use split function to count a total from list.

For example,

```
workdays = {'work': '5,6,8,10,13,14,15,18,20,22,24,25,28,30'}
```

Output should be like this

I have worked 14 days.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-list

Comment: look at link and then use a `len()` to get the number of items

Comment: Btw you are using a dictionary and not list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a list. You are using a dictionary with key and value. Get the value, `split` on comma and find length using `len`.

```
workdays = {'work': '5,6,8,10,13,14,15,18,20,22,24,25,28,30'}

print('I have worked {} days'.format(len(workdays['work'].split(','))))
```

Also, you could count the number of commas and add `1` to it to get the same result like so:

```
print('I have worked {} days'.format(workdays['work'].count(',')+1))
```

Answer (score 4):

Hint: You can access a value in a dictionary by its key:

```
>>> workdays = {'work':'1,2,3,4'}
>>> workdays['work']
'1,2,3,4'
```

Second hint: You can split a string using [`str.split(delimiter)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) like so:

```
>>> s = '1,2,3,4'
>>> s.split(',')
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Third hint: [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#len)

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.split` with `len`

**Ex:**

```
workdays = {'work': '5,6,8,10,13,14,15,18,20,22,24,25,28,30'}
print(len(workdays["work"].split(",")))
```

**Output**:

```
14
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll do something like this:

```
len(wd.get('work').split(','))
```

measure the lenght of a list containing each day