# How to merge consecutive letters and consecutive numbers from a string to a list separetely?

Tags: python

Say I have the following string:

```
    string1 = 'Twenty 20 Twelve 12'
```

I would like to convert it into a list that would keep words as strings in separate elements, and numbers in another (as integers):

```
    list1 = ['Twenty', 20, 'Twelve', 12]
```

My current code looks is:

```
    list1 = [y for y in string1.replace(' ','')]
```

and the result prints out as:

```
    ['T','w','e','n','t','y','2','0','T','w','e','l','v','e','1','2']
```

How would I be able to write a code to keep words in separate entries, and turn numbers inside the string into integers in the list?  I am a beginner to programming who is currently learning Python in parallel with C.

Comment: If you Google the phrases "Python split string" and "Python check number", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-list)

Comment: You need to use `split` to divide the string into four "words", then use the various string type checking methods (e.g. `isdigit`) to detect which are numbers.  Then you can convert as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Look into the [`.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) function.

It takes the form of

```
str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)
```

so you want your code to look like this to break it apart.

```
string1 = 'Twenty 20 Twelve 12'
string1.split()
#['Twenty', '20', 'Twelve', '12']
```

To convert the numbers to integers, just check for `.isdigit()`

```
[int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in string1.split()]
#['Twenty', 20, 'Twelve', 12]
```

if you're not familiar with [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), this is analogous to

```
values = []
for i in string1.split():
    if i.isdigit():
        values.append(int(i))
    else:
        values.append(i)

values
#['Twenty', 20, 'Twelve', 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should google it....

but you can use `split`

```
string1 = 'Twenty 20 Twelve 12'
list1=string1.split(' ')
```