# How to split each individual value between two string in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
variable=";CREATEDBY~string~1~~72~0~0~0~~~0;CREATEDBYNAME~string~1~~800~0~0~0~~~1;CREATEDBYYOMINAME~string~1~~800~0~0~0~~~2;CREATEDON~date~1~yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS~26~0~0~0~~~3;CREATEDONUTC~date~1~yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS~26~0~0~0~~~4"
```

How can I split each value which is between (`;` and `~`)?

The result will be like `CREATEDBY,CREATEDBYNAME,CREATEDBYYOMINAME,...`

I have tried the below, but it's giving the first occurrence.

```
variable[variable.find(";")+1:myString.find("~")]
```

How do I get the list of strings by using the split?

Comment: use split function . mystring.split(';') then mystirng.split('~')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-list) Note that the second answer indicates how to specify the delimiter.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using `str.split`

**Ex:**

```
variable=";CREATEDBY~string~1~~72~0~0~0~~~0;CREATEDBYNAME~string~1~~800~0~0~0~~~1;CREATEDBYYOMINAME~string~1~~800~0~0~0~~~2;CREATEDON~date~1~yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS~26~0~0~0~~~3;CREATEDONUTC~date~1~yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS~26~0~0~0~~~4"

for i in variable.strip(";").split(";"):
    print(i.split("~", 1)[0])
#or
print([i.split("~", 1)[0] for i in variable.strip(";").split(";")])
```

**Output:**

```
CREATEDBY
CREATEDBYNAME
CREATEDBYYOMINAME
CREATEDON
CREATEDONUTC

['CREATEDBY', 'CREATEDBYNAME', 'CREATEDBYYOMINAME', 'CREATEDON', 'CREATEDONUTC']
```

Answer (score 14):

We can try using `re.findall` with the pattern `;(\w+)(?=~)`:

```
variable = ";CREATEDBY~string~1~~72~0~0~0~~~0;CREATEDBYNAME~string~1~~800~0~0~0~~~1;CREATEDBYYOMINAME~string~1~~800~0~0~0~~~2;CREATEDON~date~1~yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS~26~0~0~0~~~3;CREATEDONUTC~date~1~yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS~26~0~0~0~~~4"
result = re.findall(r';(\w+)~', variable)
print(result)

['CREATEDBY', 'CREATEDBYNAME', 'CREATEDBYYOMINAME', 'CREATEDON', 'CREATEDONUTC']
```

Comment: It's rejecting if the COLUMN name has '_' (i.e CREATED_BY)

Comment: @Vicky Then use `\w+`, which includes underscores, to match your words.

Comment: @Vicky: good observation. That's why I hate Regex. You never know what they are really doing and what their intension was. It's very easy to get them wrong accidentally.

Comment: @Thomas I'm not sure that's a reason to hate Regex. `[A-Z]` should be self-explanatory that it isn't going to match underscores, and the question could have been clearer that underscores should be matched.

Comment: @ThomasWeller while I'm sure you can find [degenerate cases](https://www.regextester.com/94502) that I would totally agree with you on, the regex in question is so utterly trivial that any experienced programmer should be able to immediately understand what it does, even if their not familiar with python's particular flavor of regex. And as for getting it wrong, blaming the choice of tool for code not satisfying an incomplete spec is something I just can't get behind.

Comment: @JaredSmith: trivial or not, I can't judge. The spec is not so bad regarding the underscore: between `;` and `~`, it did not say that there should be a word (`\w`). So a `[^~]` would be closer to the spec. Next, I wonder why he says the pattern should be `;(\w+)(?=~)` but then uses `;(\w+)~` in the code.

Answer (score 5):

You can `split()` the string and then `find()` the first `~` for each one:

```
variable=";CREATEDBY~string~1~~72~0~0~0~~~0;CREATEDBYNAME~string~1~~800~0~0~0~~~1;CREATEDBYYOMINAME~string~1~~800~0~0~0~~~2;CREATEDON~date~1~yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS~26~0~0~0~~~3;CREATEDONUTC~date~1~yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS~26~0~0~0~~~4"
result = [item[:item.find('~')]  for item in  variable.split(';')]

print(result)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use regular expression with [lookahead and lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=;).*?(?=~)', variable)
['CREATEDBY', 'CREATEDBYNAME', 'CREATEDBYYOMINAME', 'CREATEDON', 'CREATEDONUTC']
```

Comment: Posted the same answer 5 minutes ago.  You don't even need lookarounds if you place the name in a capture group.

Comment: The two answers are fairly similar, yes, but I wouldn't call them the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

variable = ";CREATEDBY~string~1~~72~0~0~0~~~0;CREATEDBYNAME~string~1~~800~0~0~0~~~1;CREATEDBYYOMINAME~string~1~~800~0~0~0~~~2;CREATEDON~date~1~yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS~26~0~0~0~~~3;CREATEDONUTC~date~1~yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS~26~0~0~0~~~4"
pattern = re.compile (";(.+?)~")
matches = re.findall ( pattern, variable )
print matches
```