# How can I reorganize this list?

Tags: python, string, list, split, ip

I wait from a server to send me a list which includes ip followed by a "," followed by a port followed by ";" and then there's another tuple... and another and x tuples...

the example is:

```
127.0.0.1,45403;127.0.0.1,47146;127.0.0.1,52888
```

I want to reorganize it so I have in each loop x iteration

```
Ipx = 127.0.0.1 
Portx = 45403
```

In the next iteration of the loop

```
Ipx = 17.0.0.1
Portx = 47146
```

etc for every tuple (Ipx and Portx are different varibles)

I have tried

```
ipx , portx = lista.split(";")
        print ipx
        print portx
```

but it doesn't work...

Comment: You would receive more help on this board if you showed what you've tried. I'd suggest using `split`, like you tagged. As in, `list_of_ips = string_of_ips.split(";")` would get you half way there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-list)

Comment: @malan is not exactly what I want... I just wanna get each ip and port in different variables. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to split by ; and then by , as follows:

```
lista = "127.0.0.1,45403;127.0.0.1,47146;127.0.0.1,52888"

for address in lista.split(";"):
    ipx, portx = address.split(',')
    print(f'IP: {ipx}, Port: {portx}')
```

Comment: Also if you are using an older version of python that does not support f-strings you can substitute the last line with:
```print('IP: {}, Port: {}'.format(ipx, portx))```

Comment: thank you very much. Just exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If your server's response is a string, then you can do this:

```
inList = '127.0.0.1,45403;127.0.0.1,47146;127.0.0.1,52888'
inList = [[elem for elem in item.split(',')] for item in inList.split(';')]

for ip, port in inList:
  print(ip)
  print(port)
```

Output:

```
127.0.0.1
45403
127.0.0.1
47146
127.0.0.1
52888
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a OrderedDict and keep all ips and port in a list

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d=OrderedDict()

d.setdefault('ip',[])
d.setdefault('port',[])

inList = '127.0.0.1,45403;127.0.0.1,47146;127.0.0.1,52888'
for i in inList.split(';'):
    temp=i.split(',')
    d['ip'].append(temp[0])
    d['port'].append(temp[1])
print(d)
```

**Output**

```
OrderedDict([('ip', ['127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.1']),
             ('port', ['45403', '47146', '52888'])])
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you are halfway trhu, what you need is:

```
ipx = lista.split(";")[0].split(“,”)[0]
portx = lista.split(";")[0].split(“,”)[1]
print ipx
print portx
```

If you want to register more than one IP address I would use a dictionary as:

```
Ip_port = dict()
For i in all-data:
      a = i.split(";")[0].split(“,”)[0]
     Ip_port[a] = i.split(";")[0].split(“,”)[1]
```

Imaging that you have all you “lista” in a python list.