# How to transform results into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, character

the results of the following code is:
['di', 'me', 'medesimo', 'meco', 'mi', 'vergogno']
di
me
me
me
mi
ve

How can I change the second list:
di
me
me
me
mi
ve

into a list of this type:
['di', 'me', 'me', 'me', 'mi', 've']

Thank you in advance!

```
txt="Di me medesimo meco mi vergogno"
a=txt.lower().split()
print(a)
for x in a:
    print (x[0:2])
```

I expect to be able to have a list from which I can code a way to know if there are two or more elements that are the same. I am looking for alliteration.

Comment: Define a new list outside for loop and append `x[0:2]` to it

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/743806/1513933

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
txt="Di me medesimo meco mi vergogno"
a=txt.lower().split()
print(a)
list2 = []
for x in a:
    list2.append(x[0:2])

print(list2)
```

Output

```
['di', 'me', 'medesimo', 'meco', 'mi', 'vergogno']
['di', 'me', 'me', 'me', 'mi', 've']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
>>> txt="Di me medesimo meco mi vergogno"
>>> l = [x[:2] for x in txt.lower().split()]
>>> l
['di', 'me', 'me', 'me', 'mi', 've']
>>>
```