# Split function in python to saperate string from comma

Tags: python

how to use split to separete `'g5s,12-04-2019'` from comma.

I search for result if `a='g5s,12-04-2019'` then after split `b = 'g5s'` and `c='12-04-1=2019'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806/how-to-split-a-string-into-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

`str.split()` to the rescue:

```
a='g5s,12-04-2019'
b, c = a.split(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `x.split()` and pass the comma as input argument, like this `x.split(",")`. It means the input argument is the separator.

The `split` method returns a list which contain the elements separately. You you can unpack them one by one. Like this: `b, c = a.split(",")`

**Code:**

```
a = "g5s,12-04-2019"
print("a={a}".format(a=a))
b, c = a.split(",")
print("b={b}, c={c}".format(b=b, c=c))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
a=g5s,12-04-2019
b=g5s, c=12-04-2019
```

**FYI:**

The docstring of the `split` method.

> S.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1) -> list of strings
>
> ```
>     Return a list of the words in S, using sep as the
>     delimiter string.  If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit
>     splits are done. If sep is not specified or is None, any
>     whitespace string is a separator and empty strings are
>     removed from the result.
> ```